# Larave 8 Adding Aditional record to database with Add More/Remove more

Tags: php, laravel-8

I am new to laravel and using Laravel 8. trying to add multiple records to the database with Add more/Remove more. I am sending three fields i-e Title, content and Image. the two of the records are adding successfully but I am not sure where I am making a mistake in adding the image. please help me out.
my controller
`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\ServicesModel;
use App\Models\AditionalServicesModel;
use File;

class ServicesController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $services =ServicesModel::get();
        return view('admin.services.index')->with(compact('services'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
          return view('admin.services.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        // print_r($request->add_more); die();
        $this->validate(request(),[
            'name' =>'required',
            'icon'=> 'required',
            'services_image'=> 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:5120',
            'image_1'=> 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:5120',
        ]);
       
        $fileName =null;
        if(request()->hasFile('services_image'))
        {
            $file = request()->file('services_image');
            $fileName =md5($file->getClientOriginalName()).time().".".$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $file->move('./uploads/services',$fileName);
        }

     $services =   ServicesModel::create([
            'name'=>$request->get('name'),
            'slug'=> $request->get('slug'),
            'icon'=> $request->get('icon'),
            'featured'=>$request->get('featured'),
            'paragraph'=>$request->get('paragraph'),
            'services_image'=>$fileName,
            'add_more'=>($request->add_more==1)? 1: 0,
            'status'=> $request->get('status'),
            
        ]);
            
                 $aditional_fileName =null;
                if(request()->hasFile('image_1'))
                {
                    $file = request()->file('image_1');
                    $aditional_fileName =md5($file->getClientOriginalName()).time().".".$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                    $file->move('./uploads/services',$aditional_fileName);
                }

                if(isset($request->add_more))
                {

                    foreach($request->title as $key => $value)
                    {
                     
                     if($request->get('fileName'))
                        {

                    
                         foreach($request->fileName as $image)
                            {
                                $file =$image;
                                $fileName= md5($file->getClientOriginalName()).time().".".$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                                $file ->move(public_path().'/uploads/services',$fileName);
                            }
                        }   
                        $test= AditionalServicesModel::create([
                            'service_id'=> $services->id,
                            'title'=> $value,
                            'content'=> isset($request->description[$key])? $request->description[$key]: NULL,
                            'image'=>isset($fileName[$key])?$fileName[$key]:Null,
                         ]);

                        // print_r($test); die();
                    }
                        
                }
                
          
       
        return redirect()->to('admin/services')->with('message','Service Inserted!');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $service = ServicesModel::with('services_additional')->find($id);
        //print_r($service); die();
        return view('admin.services.edit')->with(compact('service'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
         $this->validate(request(),[
            'name' =>'required',
            'icon'=> 'required',
            'services_image'=> 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:5120',
            'image_1'=> 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:5120',
        ]);
         $services =ServicesModel::with('services_additional')->find($id);
         $servicesAditionalInformation = AditionalServicesModel::where('service_id',$services->id)->first();

        $currentImage =$services->services_image;
          $fileName =null;
        if(request()->hasFile('services_image'))
        {
            $file = request()->file('services_image');
            $fileName =md5($file->getClientOriginalName()).time().".".$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $file->move('./uploads/services',$fileName);
        }
        $services->update([
            'name'=>$request->get('name'),
            'paragraph'=>$request->get('paragraph'),
            'services_image'=>($fileName)? $fileName: $currentImage,
            'slug'=> $request->get('slug'),
            'icon'=> $request->get('icon'),
            'featured'=>$request->get('featured'),
            'add_more'=>($request->add_more==1)? 1: 0,
            'status'=> $request->get('status'),
        ]);
        if($fileName)
            File::delete(public_path().'/uploads/services/'.$currentImage);

        if($request->add_more ==1)
        {
             $services->update([
            'name'=>$request->get('name'),
            'paragraph'=>$request->get('paragraph'),
            'services_image'=>($fileName)? $fileName: $currentImage,
            'slug'=> $request->get('slug'),
            'icon'=> $request->get('icon'),
            'featured'=>$request->get('featured'),
            'add_more'=>($request->add_more==1)? 1: 0,
            'status'=> $request->get('status'),
        ]);
        }
        return redirect()->to('admin/services/')->with('message','Record Updated Successfully');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Request $request, $id)
    {
        if ($request->ajax()) 
        {
           $service= ServicesModel::find($id);
           $currentImage = $service->services_image;
           $service->delete();
            File::delete('./uploads/services/'.$currentImage);
           return 'true';
        }
       return redirect()->back()->with('error','Record Deleted Successfully');
    }

    public function status(Request $request,$id)
    {
        if($request->ajax())
        {
           $service= ServicesModel::find($id);
            $newStatus=($service->status==0)? 1 : 0 ;
            $service->update([
                'status'=>$newStatus,
            ]);
            return $newStatus;
        }
        return redirect()->back()->with('status','Status Changed');
    }
}
```

`[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EX2n.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the form. If you are using this, you should also make the filename shorter. I am sharing an ImageHelper to assist you.

```
public function imageUpload($file, String $path)
     {
         $name = date('d-m-Y-H-i-s') . rand(1,999) . '.' . $file->extension();
         $file->move(public_path($path), $name);
         $move = $path . '/' . $name;
         return $move;
     }
```

The `$file` parameter will contain the image and the `$path` parameter will be a folder name created in the `public` folder.